# Android instrumentation doesn't see my unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant, jenkins

I use http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/ to run unit tests in jenkins environment.

One sample project worked well, but for another there are strange results.
Ant outputs

```
[echo] Running tests ...
[exec]
[exec] Test results for PolideaInstrumentationTestRunner=
[exec] Time: 0.0
[exec]
[exec] OK (0 tests)
[exec]
[exec]
```

and so does adb shell am instrument -w com.mypack.tests/pl.polidea.instrumentation.PolideaInstrumentationTestRunner.

It thinks that there are no tests but there are. They successfully run from eclipse.

Comment: Try android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner to detect where is your problem.

Comment: Got it! Tried to find the differences between the project that works and the project that doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was:
in build.properties there was relative source.dir. Something like:

`source.dir=src;./../../../other.package/src;./../../and.other/src`

It compiled well, but prevented tests to run. When I set paths to absolute:

`source.dir=${workspace}/my.package/src;${workspace}/other.package/src;${workspace}/and.other/src`

tests do run.